# "nowhere" and "everywhere"

Tags: grammar, parts-of-speech

Can “***nowhere***” and “***everywhere***” function as pronoun? I searched for “*nowhere*” in one dictionary, it was stated that it can function as an “**adverb**”, “**noun**”, and “**adjective**” and in another it was stated that it only functions as an “*adverb*”. For “***everywhere***” within both it was stated that it can only function as an “**adverb**”, but it sounds to me like both can function as “**pronoun**” too. Am I right?

Comment: I don't understand what it would mean for a word to be both a ***noun*** and a ***pronoun***. What do *you* think it means?

Comment: My question is that, it might not be a "noun" but a pronoun. And also why it's considered just as an "adverb" in one dictionary and in another is considered to be "adjective" and "noun" too?